# Changing the bibliography style in the SIGGRAPH template

Tags: bibtex

I'm writing a paper using the SIGGRAPH LaTeX template (http://www.siggraph.org/instructions-authors), but I would like to have a different bibliography style.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[annual]{acmsiggraph}

\title{The Title of Your Paper Goes Here}

\author{}
\pdfauthor{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cite{Park:2006:DSI}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{template}
\end{document}
```

The citation appears like this: [Park et al. 2006], but I prefer a numbered citation style, like [1]. How can I change that in the template? I tried `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`, but that doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be against the journal style. If you still need numbered reference, then the following code will do:

```
\documentclass[annual]{acmsiggraph}

\title{The Title of Your Paper Goes Here}

\author{}
\pdfauthor{}

\makeatletter
\def\thebibliography#1{%
  \section*{%
    \refname\@mkboth{\sl\uppercase{\refname}}{\sl\uppercase{\refname}}}
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}{%
            \settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth%
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep%
            \@openbib@code%
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty%
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0em}}
  \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}%
  \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\def\@biblabel#1{\hspace*{-.5pc}[#1]\hspace*{.5pc}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cite{Park:2006:DSI}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{template}
\end{document}
```