# Singapore Beamer Template: Add numbering in Bibliography

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, formatting

I'm using the `Singapore` `beamer` theme. Using "thebibliography" I noticed that there is no numbering for the bibitems. For printing purposes this is very annoying. Tried using `\bibliographystyle` but didn't do anything.

The same for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208283/bibliography-not-numbered) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122601/changing-the-bibliography-style-in-the-siggraph-template). The second one works somehow but not quite well and has tons of side-effects I don't want.

Most likely I just don't know what to look for, but I'm really in a loss here.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here is the shortened Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test}
\cite{test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{999}

\bibitem {test} This is a testing element
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `bibliography item` template to the predefined `text` option:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test}
\cite{test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{test} This is a testing element
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting bibliography:

[image]

You might be interested in using `mode`s to control the format for the labels depending on the final document:

```
\mode<handout|article>{\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]}
```

In this way, for `article` or `handout` you'll get numbered labels, but in your `presentation` you retain the icons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's damn easy! You just saved me another 2 hours of lost time! Can you use this mode thing for hiding/showing slides? And how do I render according to the mode?

Comment: @3244611user You're welcome! To answer your questions: 1) Yes, you can say, for example, `\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\mode<hangout>{
\begin{frame}
Test1
\end{frame}}

\begin{frame}
Test2
\end{frame}

\end{document}`. 2) I don't understand what you mean with "render according to the mode".

Comment: Thanks again! You want to have two resulting pdfs accordingly, don't you? How do you get the presentation, how the handout?